# ios tumtumtum/StreamingKit play at index

Tags: ios, streaming

im using this library for ios audio streamining
https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

how i can play a queue at specific index ?

Comment: this Question is asked before  you  ... it is dupicate

Comment: no it dosnt , its different